# Searching an arrayList generated by an audio recognition

Tags: java, android, audio, arraylist

I am working on app that take the audio of the user and save them in an arrayList, then searching this array list to see if the desired word generated by the google audio API exists, so we can do actions. The action that I wanted is removed and replace it with a textview just to see if it is work properly, the audio recog is working properly, but I always got the textview text as stop. So what is the problem ?

```
package myfirstapp.myapps.me.voicerecognition;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    ListView lv;
    Button recBtn;
    static final int check = 1111;
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        recBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.recBtn);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        recBtn.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak");
        startActivityForResult(i, check);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == check && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
            String s = "start";
            for (String string : results) {
//                if(string.matches("start"))
//                    tv.setText("Ok");
//                else
//                    tv.setText("No start");
//                }
                if (string.startsWith(s))
                    tv.setText("Start");
                else
                    tv.setText("Stop");
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't break from the loop when you find a match, so unless the match is in the last String of the list, the text view will contain Stop at the end.

You might want to change it to :

```
       boolean match = false;
       for (String string : results) {
            if (string.startsWith(s)) {
                tv.setText("Start");
                match = true;
                break;
            }   
       }
       if (!match)
           tv.setText("Stop");
```

Comment: Thanks, can u help me to run the recognition on stratup of the app without using a button, I am new to android and java. Thank you.

Comment: @droidnation Did you try moving the code from `onClick` to `onCreate`?

Comment: In other word, i want the app to start recording voices without clicking a button and wait the two words stop or start to stop/start a timer during a sport event. Any help ?